# Swing application, Checker game, client/server side

Tags: javascript, java, swing, jsp

Please I need help with my project. I have created a checker game in swing java, and created a jar file for the game. It works fine when running it on Command window < java -jar checker.jar>

Now, I have designed a JSP login page using netbeans, and I want users to login into the game.

Here is my problem, how can I run a jar file on the client-side so the user logs in, then start the game ?

Comment: user need to download and play like desktop application .

Comment: Did you check whether [JNLP/JWS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html) would work for you?

Comment: @SimonKraemer Thanks for your response. I'm using Jframe. Will JNLP work with that ?

Comment: @Michael I didn't use it myself yet, but from what I have read yes. I even found an example for [AWT](https://dzone.com/articles/java-web-start-jnlp-hello). It basically is just a way to bring the application (jar) to the user in a convinient way.